# JSF component layout

Tags: jsf, layout

[image]

How can I achieve this layout in JSF (using richfaces)? I would basically like to use the rowSpan attribute of a rich:datatable, but use it for displaying components of a form (select menus, input boxes etc) instead of a collection.

Comment: Use divs or a table. You don't need to use jfs components to build the layout.

Comment: You can use the jsf `panelGrid` to render a table, but you will not be able to pull off the `colspan`, it's not supported. You'll have to use a 3rd party jsf library for anything of the sort